# Facebook The Open Graph protocol post link to wall not showing image

Tags: php, facebook, hyperlink, protocols, attachment

I'm using the (The Open Graph protocol[[Source]](http://ogp.me/)). I've searched the most of the stackoverflow, but i seems, that there aren't any answers to my question.

My `<meta>` code is:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Testing" />
<meta property="og:description" 
  content="This is the desciption testing 123" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.byui.edu/images/agriculture-life-sciences/flower.jpg" />
```

When i copy paste a link(**http://mywebsite.com/testing.php**) into facebook, on my wall, it pulls out the **og:title** and **og:description** perfectly everytime, even when i make a new PHP-file document example: testing1.php. But it dosen't show the image on the post, when i refresh the facebook 3-6 times, copy pasting the link, to the status input, it will somehow be shown, but how can it be that i need to refresh it 3-6 times, before facebook cache the image, and before the image will be shown? Is there are work around on this problem or something i've been missing? I'm using a **HTTP** url.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does indeed cache its images, and this can sometimes cause problems (such as you are experiencing). The best way I know how to "force" clean Facebook's cache is by running your website through their [debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). It used to be called "lint" when I was working with it, but I think this should have the same functionality.

Whether it works or not, I'd recommend you use it. It's a handy utility either way!